# Создание вычисляемой меры AVG в OLAP кубе MS SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, olap

Не могу создать вычисляемую AVG меру.
Есть таблица: год - значение.
Год один и тот же.

Создаю размерность - год.
Создаю меру - значение и делаю его sum.
Создаю вычисляемый член: AVG([Measures].val).
В итоге всегда получаю сумму по году что бы я не делал.
Смотрел ссылки:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146067.aspx
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224826%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Все делаю как там, но не получается.
Я новичек в OLAP.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось, нужно создать еще одну меру с агрегацией count по необходимому полю и в вычисляемом члене сумму поля разделить на кол-во.

И уже вычисляемый член использовать как финальное значение.